# Excel Pivot Table filter based on another Pivot Table output

Tags: excel, filter, report, filtering, pivot-table

I have a question related to Pivot Tables in Excel. As in the subject, what I am trying to achieve is to filter a pivot table based on yet another pivot table and its output.

The idea is that one pivot table compiles a list of items and sorts them by top 10 based on count.

At this stage, I would like to have another pivot table, which drills down more in detail into a given item and its properties and values, refresh automatically (or at least upon hitting alt-f5) so that each week or month, when the top 10 list changes, the second pivot table checks the top item and generates the detailed report based on that...

In reality this means that I would like to filter the second pivot table based on the top 10 list from the first pivot table.. if that makes sense and is clear enough?

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use pivot to filter another pivot, but simpler solution would be to add a helper column which will "choose" the top ten based on some condition. Then use that column as a filter in pivot.

Comment: Yup, that's what I do.